# Unable to connect to localhost of machine from docker container

Tags: docker, elasticsearch

My GCP ES service is port forwarded to localhost:9200 of my machine. I am able to log ingest from the local machine.

I have created JAVA script to do the same task and It is also running fine when I am running local

Now, I have created docker Image of that Java project using dockerFile and when I am creating a container, then I am getting the following error

**Connect to localhost:9200 [localhost/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)**

Docker command :
**docker run -it --net="host"  gcplogingest:latest mvn -f BEATLe/pom.xml  test  -Dcomponent=detect -DtestSuite=CommonXML/Detect_loginjectionGCP**

Note :
I have tried using --network="host" but I am still getting the same error.

Please suggest.

Comment: Have you tried exposing the port like so: `docker run -it --net="host" -p 9200:9200 gcplogingest:latest mvn -f BEATLe/pom.xml test -Dcomponent=detect -DtestSuite=CommonXML/Detect_loginjectionGCP `

Comment: I'm not familiar with logingest but it looks like you are running a test-suite for logingest in the container, and not the actual application? Is that really what you want to do? 

Does the docker container keep running or are you exiting to a console after the test run has finished?

Comment: @dravid ..Thanks for your suggestion. I tried but getting the same error. Basically I want to interact with my machine localhost from Container inside

Comment: @jishi I have Java program which Ingests log in ES running on mine localhost:9200. I have created image of that Java program and running that Image through command which I shared above. So basically mine Java program is running inside the container which is trying to connect to my local machine( MAc) localhost:9200 but this is not happening.

Comment: Have you tried removing `--net=host` and then use in your docker **host.docker.internal** instead 127.0.0.1? Consider that your host localhost should be different than your docker localhost, and once you get that removing network=host, you need to access from docker to `host.docker.internal:9200`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried removing --net=host and then use in your docker host.docker.internal instead 127.0.0.1?

Consider that your host localhost should be different than your docker localhost, and once you get that removing network=host, you need to access from docker to

```
host.docker.internal:9200
```